# Database technology for selecting geospatial data within a region?

Tags: database, geospatial, region

I need to be able to store geographically keyed data and then select data from a specific geographical region, say a polygon (on the earth), to represent the user's field of view. Is there a (free) database technology that would allow me to do this kind of selection easily?

Comment: I just found this:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/functions-for-testing-spatial-relations-between-geometric-objects.html#function_st-contains

Comment: MSSQL server has geography data type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a client-server database solution theres PostGIS, for a lightweight local solution theres SpatiaLITE. Both free and open source.